# Кто написал стихи о Лёне Королёве?

Tags: поэзия

Кто написал стихи о Лёне Королёве? Высоцкий?

Comment: Цитатку хоть дайте. Я таких стихов не знаю.

Comment: Если честно, что-то крутится на языке... "Называли королевой Ленку Королеву" - что-то такое, но абсолютно без ассоциаций. Так что  "ссылку - в студию".

Answer (score 3):

Это "Песенка о Лёньке Королёве" Булата Окуджавы.

Во дворе, где каждый вечер все играла радиола,

Где пары танцевали, пыля,

Все ребята уважали очень Леньку Королева,

И присвоили ему званье Короля...

http://teksty-pesenok.ru/rus-okudzhava/tekst-pesni-pesenka-o-lenke-koroleve-z/1880818/

Comment: Ах ты господи... Лёньку, а не Ленку. Окуджаву-то я знаю...